# How to get a batch file to locate the correct folder

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file to add a prefix to files in a specific folder and move to them a different folder.  The script works when I enter it in to the command line, but I cannot figure out how to get the batch file to locate the file to begin the process.

```
 C:\Transfers\Bell\SH
 for %a in (*.*) do ren %a SH%a
 move C:\Transfers\Bell\SH\*.* U:\I123\Bell\Inbox
```

It is the first line of the script that will not work. I have successfully run the script using the command line.  So how do I write this line?

```
 C:\Transfers\Bell\SH
```

I have tried

```
 SET PATH=%PATH%; C:\Transfers\Bell\SH
```

and

```
 cd C:\Transfers\Bell\SH
```

and

```
 PUSHD C:\Transfers\Bell\SH
```

Thank you.

Comment: use `%%a` instead of `%a` in batch-files

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What should the first line of the code be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
cd C:\Transfers\Bell\SH
for %%a in (*.*) do ren %%a SH%%a
move C:\Transfers\Bell\SH\*.* U:\I123\Bell\Inbox
```

In batch-files you need to use `%%a` instead of `%a` in for loops

Comment: @jodies I think I found an easier solution you could also try, see my updated answer.

Comment: @ Dennis That doesn't seem to work.  When I run it on the command line, it says that the file filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.  I'm pleased with the current script.  Thank you for trying to simply it though.